# Use multiple elm packages with distinct program functions

Tags: elm

I'm trying to create an elm app using both the Html.Styled package as well as the Navigation package. The issue is that they both have their own `program` function but as far as I know I only use one program for my entire app. Is it possible to use both packages' `program` function, or is there a separate way to use those two packages?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the part of your code where you import the libs? In case you are importing all from a module as in `import Xyz exposing (..)` you will have name collisions. As I have understood, you can import only the module and then use the components as `Xyz.something` to avoid name collisions. See modules part in [syntax documentation](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax)

Comment: My issue wasn't from name collisions, but how to logically resolve having two modules requiring their own program function to operate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of [`Html.Styled.program`](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-css/blob/13.1.1/src/Html/Styled.elm#L359) shows that it just wraps your styled `view` function with `toUnstyled`. You should be able to do the same thing with your input to `Navigation.program`:

```elm
import Html
import Html.Styled
import Navigation

main : Platform.Program Basics.Never model msg
main =
    Navigation.program urlParser
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , view = view >> Html.Styled.toUnstyled
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }


view : model -> Html.Styled.Html msg
view model = ...
```

I don't believe there is any general purpose solution to make multiple `program` implementations cooperate between packages, but this should get you rolling with the two packages you've referenced.